# To precompile handlerbar using gradle

Tags: gradle, handlebars.js, gradle-plugin

How to precompile handlebars template as gradle task. Also it includes templates that have transitive dependency, eg: handlebar partials. In grunt we already have plugin gradle-contrib-handlebars .